# How to test the difference of two linear regression slopes with 2 independent and one dependent variable

Tags: statistical-significance, computational-statistics

I am trying to determine if the CO2 emissions growth rate of developing countries is higher than the growth rate of developed countries. So essentially I need to compare two linear regression slopes but I'm not sure how to do that when I have 2 independent variables: year and HDI, and one dependent variable: CO2 Emissions.

I'm trying to do a different linear regression equation: y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2, with x1 = HDI, x2 = Year, b1 = regression coefficient of hdi and b2 is the regression coefficient of year.

Any tips?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "different" linear regression equation?  What is it different from and how does it implement your model, given that it doesn't appear to contain anything to distinguish developed from developing countries?

Comment: It's an extended linear regression equation. By using the regression coefficient of Human Development Index that is how I differentiate. I was looking into dummy variables just now, but I feel like this might be a better way to go. I might be going at this completely wrong. What do you suggest?

Comment: Could you explain what an "extended" linear regression equation is?  Your uses of "different," "differentiate," and "extended" appear to be unusual.

Comment: You might want to include an interaction term: $y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_1 x_2$. If $b_3$ is different from zero it would mean that countries with different HDI have different slopes over the years.

Comment: Whuber, you can just call me dumb lol. Like, it's a linear regression function I just am learning this, self teaching, as my professor hasn't gone this far. Hence why I'm asking for help from the internet. I'm thinking that the b1, for human development index, will be my way of knowing if it's developed or developing, but that won't work by the looks of it. Thank you ertxiem!

Comment: Here is a link to the spreadsheet of my data after putting everything in one column. I can share the original datasheet I made as well. I did an excel Regression stats using the HDI and year as the X axis and CO2 as the Y axis. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yZAUswL8l7XiXpKYGptjQAB8Q_2qJkXH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Ertxiem How would I calculate b3 (i don't know how to make it look fancy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've expanded my comment into an answer.

You might want to include an interaction term in your regression:
$$ y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_1 x_2$$
where $y$ represents the CO$_2$ emissions, $x_1$ is the Human Development Index (HDI) and $x_2$ is the year (as in your notation) and $x_1 x_2$ is the interaction term.

The statistical software usually allows you to include interaction terms.
If you can't, you may compute an auxiliary variable, $x_3 = x_1 x_2$ and use it in the equation:
$$ y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_3 x_3$$

If $b_3$ is different from zero it would mean that countries with different HDI have different slopes over the years. You may rewrite the equation as:
$$ y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + (b_2 + b_3 x_1) x_2$$
and interpret the interaction term in the following way: a change of $1$ unit in HDI changes the slope of the year by $b_3$ (e.g., if $b_3 = +0.1$, the slope will increase by $+0.1$ when HDI increases $1$ unit).

---

Alternatively, you may compute a different auxiliary variable
$x_3' = (x_1 - \overline{x}_1) (x_2 - \overline{x}_2)$,
where $\overline{x}_1$ and $\overline{x}_2$ are the mean HDI and the mean year.
The equation will be:
$$ y = b_0' + b_1' x_1 + b_2' x_2 + b_3' x_3'$$
the interaction term will tell us that when the HDI is $1$ unit above its mean, the slope of the year will be $b_2' + b_3'$, instead of $b_2'$, which is the slope of the year when HDI is equal to the mean.

---

On a side note, equations can be written using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
You can take a look at some examples by clicking on the edit button below this post.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I calculate $b_1, b_2$ etc? I know it's the regression coefficient but what calculation is that? I know that $b_0$ is essentially the intercept. I guess i'm still confused as to what b is

Comment: Also, what do you suggest for statistical software? At this point i'm just using Excel.

Comment: In terms of statistical software, R has an excellent quality to cost ratio: it is very good and is free. In Excel, as far as I know, there is the "Data Analysis" toolpak that might be able to perform the multiple linear regression and compute for you the coefficients $b_j$.